# Querying collection object using SqlFieldQuery in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, ignite

Sample Class

```
public class PersonImpl{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName
   private HashMap<Integer,String> attributes;
}
```

While using sqlFields query, it works with firstName and lastName, but all attributes cannot be fetched with sqlFieldsQuery

For example, select firstName from PersonImpl gives the result, but select attributes from PersonImpl does not fetch results and gives error Failed to deserialize Object

Is it not possible to fetch collections with ApacheIgnite.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some more of your code? This should work. I tried this and it worked for example:

```
        var cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<Long,PersonImpl>()
                .setName("PERSON")
                .setIndexedTypes(Long.class, PersonImpl.class);
        var cache = ignite.<Long,PersonImpl>getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration);

        var attr = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        attr.put(1,"London");
        attr.put(2,"United Kingdom");
        cache.put(1L, new PersonImpl("John", "Smith", attr));

        try (var cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select attributes from PersonImpl where _key = ?").setArgs(1L))) {
            for (var e : cursor) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the Ignite Version you are using, it was working for me in 2.6 but stopped working after upgrade to 2.11.1

Comment: Works correctly in 2.11.1, 2.12.0 and GridGain 8.8.13.

Comment: Also if instead of HashMap<Integer,String> attributes, if it is Map<Integer,Employee> where Employee has other attributes in it, how can we do that